# Relacionar dos modelos en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy en problema al poder relacionar dos modelos en mongodb. Estuve viendo por algunos foros los métodos `populate()`, `aggregate()`. Pero no funcionan para el caso (creo).

Tengo **modelo A** `{title : 'hola'}`, **modelo B** `{id_a : '2der45g', data : 'etc'}`. En este caso lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
var reportStatus = function(request, reply) {
        var result = [];
        models.Eventos.find({},{title: 1}, function(err, eventos) {
            if(err) throw err;
            models.Report.find({}).where('evento').equals(eventos[0]._id).exec(function(err, reporte) {
                eventos[0]['reporte'] = reporte;
                reply(JSON.stringify(eventos));
            });
        });
    }
```

El **problema** es que al hacer `print`, no me esta agregando reporte al primer **objeto A**, se entiendo?

Espero de su ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Amigo yo tuve el mismo problema pero encontré una forma de relacionar un documento con otros dos mediante referencia al *ObjectId*. Te dejo el código para ver si te sirve. Esta con *mongoose* y echo en *Nodejs*.

**En algunas líneas de código no se utilizó `function(err,elemento){}`, se utilizado la nueva forma de *ECMAScript 6* `(err,elemento) => {}`.**

Los modelos a utilizar.

Primer modelo de un "alumno".

```js
//sirve para poder usar nuevas instrucciones en javascript
'use strict'

//guardamos en una variable las propiedades del modulo mongosse en node_modules
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//se carga en una variable la propiedad de esquema
//var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//creamos el esquema en un objeto(se podria decir que es la estructura de una tabla o la de la collecion de mongo)
var AlumnoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    rut: String,
    nombre: String,
    apaterno: String,
    amaterno: String,
    nacimiento: String,
    edad: Number,
    estadocivil: String,
    nacionalidad: String,
    direccion: String,
    comuna: String,
    celular:String,
    telefono: String,
    correo: String,
    actividad: String,
    escolaridad: String
});

//exportamos el objeto y pasamos 2 parametros
//el primer parametro es el nombre de la coleccion(tabla)
module.exports = mongoose.model('alumno', AlumnoSchema);
```

Segundo modelo de un "curso":

```js
//sirve para poder usar nuevas instrucciones en javascript
'use strict'

//guardamos en una variable las propiedades del modulo mongosse en node_modules
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//se carga en una variable la propiedad de esquema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//creamos el esquema en un objeto(se podria decir que es la estructura de una tabla o la de la collecion de mongo)
var CursosSchema = Schema({
    codigocurso: String,
    lugar: String,
    fechainicio: String,
    fechatermino:String,
});

//exportamos el objeto y pasamos 2 parametros
//el primer parametro es el nombre de la coleccion(tabla)
module.exports = mongoose.model('curso', CursosSchema);
```

Ahora el tercer modelo en donde se guardan la referencia a los *ObjectId* de los otros dos modelos anteriores.

Modelo de "cursoalumnos":

```js
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CursoAlumnosSchema = Schema({
    //guardamos el Objetcid del modelo "curso"
    codigocurso: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'curso' },
    //guardamos el Objetcid del modelo "alumno"
    rutalumno: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'alumno' },
    licencia: String,
    ncontrato: String,
    total: Number,
    saldo: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('cursoalumno', CursoAlumnosSchema);
```

Luego creamos la función para obtener todos los elementos de la colección "cursoalumnos". En la primera búsqueda se ejecuta la opción **"Populate"** para obtener los datos de la colección "alumno". Luego antes de enviar la respuesta con el elemento se realiza la opción populate sobre el modelo "curso" y así rellenar con la información de dicha colección.

```js
function getCursoAlumnos(req,res){

    CursoAlumnos.find().populate({patch: 'rutalumno'}).exec((err, cursoalumno) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message:'Error de conexión a la BD'});
        }else{
            if(!cursoalumno){
                res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe el curso'});
            }else{
                Curso.populate(cursoalumno, {path: 'codigocurso'}, (err, docingreso) => {
                    
                    if(err){
                        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticiona la BD'});
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).send(cursoalumno);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    
}

module.exports = {
    getCursoAlumnos
}
```

Luego de realizar otros pasos en el servidor de *NodeJS* para probarlo este es el resultado con datos genéricos.

```html
[
    {
        "_id": "59e0357117fb951fccc948bc",
        "saldo": 150000,
        "total": 150000,
        "ncontrato": "002",
        "licencia": "A1",
        "rutalumno": {
            "_id": "59d5031e00156810fc896c6b",
            "escolaridad": "universitaria",
            "actividad": "trabajador",
            "correo": "usuario@usuario.cl",
            "telefono": "755656561",
            "celular": "6745544545",
            "comuna": "molina",
            "direccion": "villa",
            "nacionalidad": "chilena",
            "estadocivil": "soltero",
            "edad": 29,
            "nacimiento": "01-10-2594",
            "amaterno": "torres",
            "apaterno": "contreras",
            "nombre": "sergio",
            "rut": "16646011-5",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "codigocurso": {
            "_id": "59decd99fa96d61190d2ca12",
            "fechatermino": "10-12-2016",
            "fechainicio": "10-12-2016",
            "lugar": "curico",
            "codigocurso": "tal-cur-001",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Sin la opción populate quedaría de la siguiente forma:

Obtendríamos los datos de la colección "cursoalumnos" sin la referencia a los datos de las otras colecciones.

```html
[
    {
        "_id": "59e0357117fb951fccc948bc",
        "saldo": 150000,
        "total": 150000,
        "ncontrato": "002",
        "licencia": "A1",
        "rutalumno": "59d5031e00156810fc896c6b",
        "codigocurso": "59decd99fa96d61190d2ca12",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Ojala te sirva ya que me costo llegar al resultado, es un código simple ya que no posee búsquedas ni ordenamiento especifico.

Answer (score -1):

Hay dos formas de relacionar documentos en mongo:

1. Embebido
2. Referenciado

Embebido es que tu colección tenga un atributo que contenga todo el dato de otro modelo, ejemplo:

```
{
_id: ObjectId('...'),
name: 'test',
data: {
    data1: '',
    data2: 100,
    data3: [],
    dataN: {}
  }
}
```

Y referenciado usando el ejemplo anterior sería:

```
{
_id: ObjectId('...'),
name: 'test',
data: objectId('...')
}
```

¿Cuál es la mejor manera? Depende si tus consultas serán pesadas y afectarán el rendimiento, por ejemplo si sólo quieres los nombres, ¿Para qué cargar toda la info embebida? puedes decir que puedes hacer filtros, pero al hacer eso, *Mongo primero carga todo el documento y después lo filtra* lo cuál estaría afectando el rendimiento de todos modos. Y bueno, otros criterios son si es esencial la relación de tus documentos para que tu app cumpla su función. Pueden haber otros criterios, depende mucho de los requerimientos y del equipo de desarrollo.

Si es por referencia, para que las consultas con populate() funcionen, el id del documento referenciado debe ser del tipo **ObjectId**, sino, no funcionará.

El ejemplo que pones:

```
{id_a : '2der45g', data : 'etc'}
```

Si lo tienes así, para mongo el _id es un String, no un ObjectId. Es mucha diferencia pues la forma de cada uno se basa en diferentes bytes.

Cuando hagas tu modelo, debes declarar su tipo como ObjectId e indicar con cuál otro modelo hace referencia. Te pondré un ejemplo pero te dejo [acá la documentación de mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Con eso ya puedes usar populate():

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' }).
  populate('_creator').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The creator is %s', story._creator.name);
    // prints "The creator is Aaron"
  });
```

Por otro lado, si es una relación embebida, basta con un método find() y acceder al atributo que contiene la información que deseas, pero digamos que la mayoría de las veces querrás hacerlo por referencia, depende de tus requerimientos y si lo llegas a usar, deben haber buenas razones.

En conclusión, *revisa cómo estás declarando tus modelos* para que asociarlos sea posible, puedes usar estos ejemplos para hacer una prueba y luego lo adaptas a tus modelos.